# Can you force a Clojure macro to evaluate its arguments?

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to define a helper function that wraps `clojure.test/deftest`. Here's my general idea:

```
(defn test-wrapper
  [name & body]
  (deftest (symbol (clojure.string/replace name #"\W" "-")) body)))
```

However, since the first argument to `deftest` is unevaluated, it throws an exception since it is a form and not a symbol. Is there any way to force the form to evaluate first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better approach here is to make test-wrapper a macro. Macros don't evaluate their arguments, unless you tell them to. You can manipulate the arguments and substitute them in some generated code, as follows:

```
(use 'clojure.test)

(defmacro test-wrapper
  [name & body]
  (let [test-name (symbol (clojure.string/replace name #"\W" "-"))]
    `(deftest ~test-name ~@body)))

(test-wrapper "foo bar" (is (= 1 1)))

(run-tests)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to make a macro (that you didn't write) evaluate its arguments.

The best way to make your `test-wrapper` do what you want it to would be to turn it into a macro itself. Then it could evaluate the call to `symbol` itself and then expand to a call to `deftest` with the result of the call to `symbol` as the first argument.